# What does it mean the button is _armed_?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

What does it mean the button is *armed*?

Comment: Press for button disarmament!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is similar to the *pressed* state. The difference is that *armed* means that the mouse remains pressed within the bounds of the button. See [this reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

The button is pressed (but not released)! See this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html).

*Pressed* means either by mouse button (pointer still within button regions) or by space button on keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The JButton state of being hold state with mousepressed event is called armed state